# Can the Bootstrap Modal be extended using jQueryUI's widget factory?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm familiar with how jQuery's widget factory can extend the functionality of existing jQuery components with

`$.widget('rv.better_dialog', $.ui.dialog, config_options_hash);`

where `$.ui.dialog` is the component's constructor being passed into the widget factory. However, I need to extend the functionality of **Bootstrap's** components with `$.widget()`; something like:

`$.widget('rv.bootstrap_dialog', $.fn.modal.Constructor, databacked_configuration);`

I got the Modal's constructor format from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/javascript/

Needless to say, my above attempt isn't working, and I've also tried injecting a noConflict() version of the modal constructor. My question is, can this be done at all? Can non-jQueryUI components be extended with jQuery's $.widget()? Or is $.widget() compatible only with jQuery components?

Comment: `$.widget()` is only compatible with components created using the widget factory. *Most* of the examples of those created using the widget factory are jQuery UI, but some are not. I see no evidence Bootstrap's components used the widget factory.

Comment: @hereticMonkey Thanks, my suspicion was the same - that $.widget() won't play with non-jQuery components. In my research, I too have not (yet) seen any examples of a generic/non-jQuery component being used as the basis for an extended widget

Answer (score 0):

Just to close out this question for anyone else who might see it - there seems to be no way to extend non-jQuery components with jQuery's widget factory. boo.